# Axios Error : Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, form-data

I'm trying to upload a buffer (file) to an external server and I've been getting this error from axios since the morning.

```
Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, here's my code below in nodeJS

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', new Blob([file]), '...');

const config = this.getConfig();
try {
  const res = await axios.post(
    `...`,
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
        ...
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-Length': file.byteLength,
        ...
      },
    },
  );
  if (!res) return;
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof AxiosError) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}
```

Also when I googled the error, it seems like people are getting it as well using the same axios version (0.27.2)

Here's an example:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4710

Answer (score 0):

If `file` is already a `Buffer`, you don't need to wrap it in `Blob()`. The [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#usage) package is capable of directly handling buffers and streams.

You're also missing the [content-type header produced by `FormData`](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#axios) which will include the appropriate mime boundary tokens

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file, "..."); // directly append file

const config = this.getConfig();
try {
  await axios.post(`...`, formData, {
    headers: {
      // ...
      "Content-Length": file.byteLength,
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
    },
  });
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof AxiosError) {
    console.error(e.toJSON());
  }
}
```